# SQL Server BCP Bulk insert Pipe delimited with text qualifier format file

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp

I have a csv file which is vertical pipe delimited with every column also with a text qualifier of ".

I have been trying for ages to try and get the BCP format file to work, but no luck.

I have the following staging table:

```
[ID] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
[SUB_ID] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NULL,
[CODE1] [VARCHAR](20) NULL,
[CODE2] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NULL,
[DATE] [DATE] NULL
```

Data in csv:

```
"ID"|"SUB_ID"|"CODE1"|"CODE2"|"DATE"
"HAJHD87SADAD9A87SD9ADAS978DAA89D09AS"|"7510"|"N04FY-1"|"359420013"|"08/08/2018"
```

Format file:

```
14.0
5
1   SQLCHAR   0  0   '"|"'  1  ID      ""
2   SQLCHAR   0  0   '"|"'  2  SUB_ID  ""
3   SQLCHAR   0  0   '"|"'  3  CODE1   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4   SQLCHAR   0  0   '"|"'  4  CODE2   ""
5   SQLCHAR   0  0   '"\n"' 5  DATE    ""
```

When I try to execute using the following SQL statement:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[TEST]
FROM 'G:\DATA\TABLE.csv'  
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,
      FORMATFILE = 'G:\DATA\TEST.fmt')
```

I get this error

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I can't work out where it is going wrong. Is it a data type mismatch or are my FIELDTERMINATOR and ROWTERMINATOR incorrect? Any ideas will be greatly received, I've tried so many combinations.

Comment: Oh, wait! I left something off. Because your first column also begins with a delimiter, you have to have  way to let BCP ignore the very first doublequote in the file. I'll that in a bit...

Comment: Thanks, Jamie, I did what you said with regards to Notepadd++ and it turns out there were some extra carriage returns at the end of the file that was throwing things off. I deleted that line and it all worked after that. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the BCP program only recognizes the doublequote as the container of the delimiter. So, using the single quote is causing an error.

Second, since the delimiter you want to specify "|" includes the doublequote character that BCP requires you to use to use to enclose your delimiter, you have to use the escape character to get the BCP program to ignore the quotes you want to use as delimiters. The escape character is the backslash character. So...

Instead of "|"... use... "\"|\""

This will tell BCP to ignore the doublequots preceded by a backslash and just treat them as any other character.

Third, you must account for the first field that has a preceding doublequote. The "|" terminator I mentioned above wont account for the opening doublequote at the beginning of each line for the first field.

To handle that you must add a "dummy" field to your format file and assign it's terminator as \" (or actually "\"" in the format file). Then, since you now have one more field in the file than you have in the table, you must offset your column numbering to tell BCP skip this new field that is terminated by the first doublequote in the file

Last, the last field is not terminated by just a newline character "\n". It is also termed by a doublequote (no pipe character included). So, we must customimze the final field terminator (which is actually the line/row terminator). Like this "\"\n".

Your format file will now look like this:

```
14.0
5
1   SQLCHAR   0  0   "\""  0  dummy_field   ""
2   SQLCHAR   0  0   "\"|\""  1  ID      ""
3   SQLCHAR   0  0   "\"|\""  2  SUB_ID  ""
4   SQLCHAR   0  0   "\"|\""  3  CODE1   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5   SQLCHAR   0  0   "\"|\""  4  CODE2   ""
6   SQLCHAR   0  0   "\"\n" 5  DATE    ""
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: HI Jamie, thanks ever so much for taking your time on this. I would not have thought about the dummy field. I have implemented your suggestion but get the following error.  Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: ah! I forgot the last field. It is not terminated by \n is it? No. It is terminated by a doublequote and a newline. So, last line terminator shoudl be "\"\n". Ive updated the answer.

Comment: So i still get an error with the new amendment. But i captured the error using the ERRORFILE command. This is what the file says.  Row 12850 File Offset 1390555 ErrorFile Offset 0 - HRESULT 0x80004005. This is the actual offending article. 01/01/1992"01/01/1992"

Comment: This is the actual last line in the file: "58D770B25"|"6674"|"G20"|"99042012"|"01/01/1992"

Comment: This was the actual error on SQL: Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.

Comment: I suggest using a good text editor. Notepad++ or UltraEdit... many free versions out there. You need to inspect the file. The good news is that it's loading (correct?)? Now, the issue seems to be the data itself. If the first error in the log was for row 12850, that means 12849 rows were good. Use a good text editor (not notepad or wordpad or Word) and inspect that line. These good text editors will show ALL characters (white space characters and such).

Comment: yes, the error file option with BCP is great. very accurate and good errors in there. Great for when the data is the issue. Im guessing there is some control character problem ( crlf or newline, or something along those lines). But THAT.... is another question ;)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was changing

ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'

to

ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'.

Simply executing something like this if a rewrite it to your case:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[TEST]
FROM 'G:\DATA\TABLE.csv' 
WITH 
(   
    FIRSTROW = 2 
    , FIELDTERMINATOR ='|'
    , ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

we must use `0x0a` which is an encoded form of `\n`

Also, mandatory to specify `FIELDTERMINATOR` either by comma, pipe or any other delimeter

```
BEGIN
truncate table [dbo].[YourTableName]
BULK
INSERT ]dbo].[YourTableName]
   FROM 'D:\RXS RJ Sheets\GLICHealth_PharmacyFeed_20230501_20230531.txt'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW =2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)
end
```