# Export data with bcp utility with double quotes

Tags: sql-server, regex, shell, bcp

I'm trying to exporting data from MS sql server by using **bcp utility** command line. The problem is that in the exported output is missing the first double quote at the first line and I cannot explain the reason.

Below the command that I'm using for the export:

```
 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp db_schema out dump.csv -c -t"\",\"" -r"\"\n\"" -S my_host -U my_user
```

But the output result is missing the first double quotes on first line (only the first line) of the exported csv file:

```
801","40116","Hazelnut MT -L","Thursday Promo","Large","","5.9000","","801","1.0000","","3.6500","2.2500",".0000","default","","","","","Chatime","02/06/2014","09125a9cfffd4143a00e73e3b62f15f2","CB01","",".0000","5.9000","6.9000",".0000",".0000",".0000",".0000",".0000",".0000","0","","0","0","0","","","","","","","","","Modern Milk Tea","","","0","","","1","0","","","","","","","","0","Hau Chan","","","","","","","","","","0","","","","","","","-1","","","","","","","","","","","","0","00000000420714AA","2014-06-02","1900-01-01","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The values you're passing in for -t and -r look suspicious to me. What do you want the field and row terminators (respectively) to be?

Comment: @BenThul I'll update the question with the expected result and the wrong result that I'm getting.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the field names, you can try the following:

```
Create Table [names]
(
Id Int,
fname VarChar(15),
lname VarChar(25)
)
Insert Into names Values
(1, 'Jim', 'Morrison'),
(2,'Robert', 'Plant'),
(3,'Janis', 'Joplin')
```

BCP command: Using quotename() with char(34)

(This BCP command uses a Trusted connection)

```
bcp "SELECT quotename(Cast(Id As VarChar(15)),char(34)), quotename(fname,char(34)), quotename(lname,char(34)) FROM names" queryout dump.csv -c -t"," -S SERVER -d DBNAME -T
```

Result:

```
"1","Jim","Morrison"
"2","Robert","Plant"
"3","Janis","Joplin"
```

Comment: Clever use of `quotename()`. I'm putting that one in my bag of tricks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that you also have a line at the end of the file that is just a single double-quote. Why? With the command line switches you've provided, you're saying "end every field with `","` and every row with `"\n"`". And that's what it's doing.

So, the second and subsequent lines start with a double-quote because the previous line *ends* with one.

Clippy DBA says "it looks like you're trying to produce a CSV". Without knowing why, it's hard for me... er... Clippy to suggest an alternative. Specifically, what is going to be reading this file? Will you be reading this with Excel or something else that's expecting a specific format? WIll you be importing it into another database table?

Answer (score 0):

The quotename answer provided by level3looper will work in your case.

For completeness, Im providing a solution I've given in the past for the same purpose.
I like this one a little better because it keeps the definition of formatting in the format file, which is where I prefer to go to get that info. The quotename is a good solution for quick, adhoc work, but for automation, business process, I would recommand the link below.

Essentially, you just add a "dummy" column to the beginning of the definition of the extract file and delimit that column with a single doublequote. Then you also note in the format file to skip the first column. This gives you just the doublequote at the start of the line.

[sql server bcp bulk insert pipe delimited with text qualifier format file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958418/sql-server-bcp-bulk-insert-pipe-delimited-with-text-qualifier-format-file/55959635#55959635)