# SQL query to flatfile csv with column header, separator column ";" and text qualifier double-quote

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sqlcmd, bcp

I would like export SQL query to csv flatfile in ExecuteProcessTask in SSIS.

I can't see an export with the header, separator and qualify it as text.
I tried with sqlcmd and bcp.

For information, I am obliged to use a SELECT * because the view in FROM is a variable and I have to display all the column.

With sqlcmd :

```
sqlcmd -S  ServerName -d dbName -E -Q "SELECT * FROM vPBI_Tasks WHERE [project Leader] like 'ProjectLeaderName'" -o "exportFile.csv" -W -s";"
```

Extract Result :

```
Scope;Project type;Activity type;OBS;Customer;Contr...
-----;------------;-------------;---;--------;-----...
ESP;ESP - Amendment;NULL;NULL;GSA;ESP_Amendment#13;...
ESP;ESP - Amendment;NULL;NULL;GSA;ESP_Amendment#13;...
ESP;ESP - Amendment;NULL;NULL;GSA;ESP_Amendment#13;...
```

I would like :

```
"Scope";"Project type";"Activity type";"OBS";"Customer";"Contra..."
ESP";"ESP - Amendment";"NULL";"NULL";"GSA";"ESP_Amendment#13";""
ESP";"ESP - Amendment";"NULL";"NULL";"GSA";"ESP_Amendment#13";""
ESP";"ESP - Amendment";"NULL";"NULL";"GSA";"ESP_Amendment#13";""
```

With bcp :

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM vPBI_Resources WHERE [project Leader] like 'ProjectLeaderName'" queryout "exportFile.csv" -c -t ; -S ServerName -T
```

Result :

- I don't have header
- I don't have text qualifier

Comment: *"I can't see an export with the header, separator and qualify it as text"* where are you looking? They are clear options in the options [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlqdC.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0viT4.png) in the flat file data source.

Comment: In bcp or sqlcmd. I don't use classical flatfile data destination, I use Execute Process Task Editor because I can't go through a flat file connection.

Comment: SQL query is a regular expression : 
"SELECT * FROM " +  @[User::SQLView] + " WHERE " +  @[User::WhereClause]

Comment: *"because I can't go through a flat file connection."* why not? That will make what you're after here trivial.

Comment: The problem I have is that if I create a flat file connection, I have to define the names and number of exported columns but this varies depending on @User::SQLView. I'm falling down, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer given to an earlier, similar request:

[SQL Server BCP Bulk insert Pipe delimited with text qualifier format file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958418/sql-server-bcp-bulk-insert-pipe-delimited-with-text-qualifier-format-file/55959635#55959635)

Essentially, you need to use a BCP format file. When you build your BCP command, include the -f option and specify the location of the format file. In the format file, you specify your delimiter not as just the semi-colon character, but as ";" (that's two dbl-quote chars with a semi-colon between).

Theres a little more to it than that, but the link has the rest.

To get the header included, you just need to use 2 queries essentially. One query will be for the header and another query will be for the detail records. You can "union" the two queries together using "queryout" option of BCP. You will have to convert all your detail data to varchar data types so they can be queried together into a single file. But since you are already going out to a text file anyway, this shouldn't cause an issue. There are other answers that detail how to get a header included in this manner. I'll add one soon as an edit. You can also query out the header and detail records as two separate files (2 separate bcp commands) and just merge them together with a OS/script command.

Answer (score 0):

I had indeed thought about this solution but I was confused by the problem of adding the double-quote at the beginning and ending of the line.

The workaround solution I found is a script in C#.
[http://neil037.blogspot.com/2013/07/ssis-script-task-to-export-data-from.html](http://I%20had%20indeed%20thought%20about%20this%20solution%20but%20I%20was%20confused%20by%20the%20problem%20of%20adding%20the%20guillement%20at%20the%20beginning%20of%20the%20line.%20%20The%20workaround%20solution%20I%20found%20is%20a%20script%20in%20C#.%20http://neil037.blogspot.com/2013/07/ssis-script-task-to-export-data-from.html)

I put the C# code below, it will be used for other people:).

```
public void Main()
    {

        String filePath = Dts.Variables["User::temporyExportFilePath"].Value.ToString();
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        CreateCSVFile(GetTableData(), filePath);

    }

    public DataTable GetTableData()
    {

        String sqlQuery = Dts.Variables["User::sqlQuery"].Value.ToString();
        String connectionString = Dts.Variables["User::stringDatabaseConnection"].Value.ToString();
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connect);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adap.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }


    public void CreateCSVFile(DataTable dt, string strFilePath)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);
        int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
        {
            // Write text qualifier double-quote + value + double-quote
            sw.Write("\"" + dt.Columns[i] + "\"");
            if (i < iColCount - 1)
            {
                //Parser
                sw.Write(";");
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        // Now write all the rows.
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
            {
                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                {
                    // Write text qualifier double-quote + value + double-quote
                    sw.Write("\"" + dr[i].ToString() + "\"");
                }
                if (i < iColCount - 1)
                {
                    //Parser
                    sw.Write(";");
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        }
        //Close file and all data writing
        sw.Close();
    }
```