# BCP update database table base on output from powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, bcp

I have 4 files with the same csv header as following

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
```

But I only required data from `Column2,Column3,Column4` for import the data into SQL database using `BCP` . I am using the PowerShell to select the columns that I want and import the required data using `BCP` but my powershell executed with no error and there are not data updated in my database table. May I know how to set the `BCP` to import the output from Powershell to database table. Here are my powershell script

```
$filePath = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\test\*' -Include $filename
$desiredColumn = 'Column2','Column3','Column4'

foreach($file in $filePath)
{
  write-host $file
 $test = import-csv $file | select $desiredColumn
 write-host $test
 $action = bcp <myDatabaseTableName> in $test -T -c -t";" -r"\n" -F2 -S <MyDatabase>
}
```

These are the output from the powershell script

```
D:\test\sample1.csv
@{column2=111;column3=222;column4=333} @{column2=444;column3=555;column4=666}
D:\test\sample2.csv
@{column2=777;column3=888;column4=999} @{column2=aaa;column3=bbb;column4=ccc}
```

Comment: Your file is shown to have a comma (,) as the delimiter, but your BCP command is set to (-t";") which tells bcp that the semi-colon character is your field delimiter. Which is your actual delimiter in the files? Comma or semi-colon?

Comment: Last, rather than ask powershell to recreate the row of data, you can use BCP to skip a column. Can you accept that as an answer? Or must you use powershell to transform the file before BCP? I would not use a scripting language to manipulate the data coming in, i would just use BCP or SSIS. Why not just use SSIS for this? I have my reasons, but curious why you have chosen not to.

Comment: I am not familiar with BCP or either BCP. So the BCP is able to do the job? my original csv delimiter is comma

Comment: the desired output is I need to update the database table column based on the data from CSV. My CSV have four columns but my DB table only have 3 columns

Comment: Yes, BCP can do the job. SSIS can do this as well. But BCP might be more up your alley as you seem more comfortable with scripting and might want to avoid a gui dev environment solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you can't *update* a table with `bcp`. It is used to bulk load data. That is, it will either *insert* new rows or *export* existing data into a flat file. Changing existing rows, usually called as updating, is out of scope for `bcp`. If that's what you need, you need to use another a tool. `Sqlcmd` works fine, and Powershell's got [`Invoke-Sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) for running arbitary TSQL statements.

Anyway, the [BCP utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) has notoriously tricky syntax. As far as I know, one cannot bulk load data by passing the data as parameter to `bcp`, a source file must be used. Thus you need to save the filtered file and pass its name to `bcp`.

Exporting a filtered CSV is easy enough, just remember to use `-NoTypeInformation` switch, lest you'll get `#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` as your first row of data. Assuming the `bcp` arguments are well and good (why `-F2` though? And Unix newlines?).

Stripping double quotes requires another an edit to the file. Scrpting Guy [has a solution](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-from-csv-files-by-using-powershell/).

```
foreach($file in $filePath){
  write-host $file
  $test = import-csv $file | select $desiredColumn
  # Overwrite filtereddata.csv, should one exist, with filtered data
  $test | export-csv -path .\filtereddata.csv -NoTypeInformation
  # Remove doulbe quotes
  (gc filtereddata.csv) | % {$_ -replace '"', ''} | out-file filtereddata.csv -Fo -En ascii
  $action = bcp <myDatabaseTableName> in filtereddata.csv -T -c -t";" -r"\n" -F2 -S <MyDatabase>
}
```

Depending on your locale, column separator might be semicolon, colon or something else. Use `-Delimiter '<character>'` switch to pass whatever you need or change `bcp`'s argument.

Erland's got [a helpful page](http://www.sommarskog.se/bulkload.html) about bulk operations. Also, see Redgate's [advice](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/).

Comment: is there any command that can ignore the double quotation mark from export-csv?

Comment: @HeartBreakKID Why? It's part of CSV standard to enclose data in double quotes. Anyway, there isn't built-in functionality, so doing a search and replace as text would probably work. You can also try your luck with [TSQL bulk insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: because the data need to import to database using BCP, cant accept any double quotation. but anyway thanks for your guide, I manage to update it to database table but with double quotation on it.

Comment: @HeartBreakKID See the edit about removing double quotes from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Without need to modify the file first, there is an answer here about how bcp can handle quoted data.

[BCP in with quoted fields in source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958418/sql-server-bcp-bulk-insert-pipe-delimited-with-text-qualifier-format-file/55959635#55959635)

Essentially, you need to use the -f option and create/use a format file to tell SQL your custom field delimiter (in short, it is no longer a lone comma (,) but it is now (",")... comma with two double quotes. Need to escape the dblquotes and a small trick to handle the first doulbe quote on a line. But it works like a charm.

Also, need the format file to ignore column(s)... just set the destination column number to zero. All with no need to modify the file before load. Good luck!